# Using NSPredicate to filter Core Data entities without property equal to any of array property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have a set of `Price` in Core Data

```
    price1 = Price.newInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!)
    price1.price = 1
    price1.size = 1
    price1.market = market1

    price2 = Price.newInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!)
    price2.price = 2
    price2.size = 1
    price2.market = market1

    price3 = Price.newInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!)
    price3.price = 3
    price3.size = 1
    price3.market = market1

    self.save()
```

Then I have an update set

```
    let p1 = PriceUpdate(price: 1, size: 2)
    let p2 = PriceUpdate(price: 4, size: 2)

    let updates = [p1, p2]
```

And I want to fetch all `Price` objects in persistent store that don't have a price equal to any of the updates price. In the example that would be the `price2` and `price3` as price 2 and 3 are not in updates (1 and 4)

I've tried something like this but I'm not sure.

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Price", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@.%K", "price", updates, "price")
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your can make one more attribute and insert 0 in your table attribute... and when you update your table than insert 1 in new attribute.. so when you fetched the data from table simple make a query with new attribute having 1 in table ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide details of `PriceUpdate`, but I assume it's a struct or similar.  Start by constructing an array holding just the prices:

```
let updatePrices = updates.map() { $0.price }
```

Then build a predicate which filters out the `Price` objects if their `price` is in the above array:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT %K IN %@", "price", updatePrices)
```